# Android retrieving image resource drawable id from Sqlite and set it as source for an image in customised listview

Tags: android, image, sqlite, listview

I have a table user with fields Name(text) Image_id(integer, image resource_id). I am saving the image resource ids as an integer values in sqlite db. I am also loading a customised listview with image(user image), text(User name). The adapter for listview is created from data retrieved from db. Image View for each row as follows

```
       holder.userImage.setImageResource(userList.get(position).image);
```

But Sometimes my images gets misplaced, not showing the correct image for the user. When uninstall and install the application, then everything is fine. Why showing such unexpected behaviour?

Comment: why using resource id?

Comment: @pskink Can you please suggest any other way.

Comment: place images in assets folder